# How can I used my old whatsapp account with new sim

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

Good day,

My old sim is expired and I bought  new one , I forgot to change my number in whatsapp before I formeted it...

It is possible to retrieve my old whatsapp account?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, only if you have access to the number with which your WhatsApp account is associated. Your question does not give all the necessary details.

Comment: My old sim is expired already i can

Comment: My old sim is already expired

Comment: Can you receive messages on that SIM? If yes, you can use your old WhatsApp account.